# Django MPTTModel Tree structure gets corrupted inside Redis Cache upon concurrent creation and retrieval operations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt, django-cache

### **Usecase:**

We've got a case where one of our models **Content** represents hierarchical data for our organization and for maintaining this hierarchy we've used **django-mptt** package which is based on the **Modified Preorder Tree Transversal** algorithm and for making the response time faster for the client, we've introduced the Redis Cache via **django-cacheops** package for our models.

[image]

*Img src = http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/*

### **Problem:**

As we've used **MPTTModel** for maintaining the **hierarchical structure** of our data inside the database, when **concurrent CREATE** and **READ** requests are made by the clients we end up with **Corrupted data inside our Redis Cache.**

### **Reason:**

When we do a **create** operation on the tree, The **MPTTModel Package** actually creates the instance of the object inside the database and **build/maintains** the tree and while the **MPTTModel package** is **building/maintaining** the tree at the same time a **read** request is made to that instance which is then resulting in **corrupted data** inside the **Redis Cache**

***Note:-** our system architecture is based on **Microservice Architecture** due to which we've got a couple of requests being made by different Microservices.*

Has anyone faced such an issue before and what solution can we use to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you run the entire create request in a transaction so that the changes are committed in one go? Setting [ATOMIC_REQUESTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests) in your DB settings might be worth looking at

Comment: I understand your proposition of creating atomic requests but due to some restrictions caused by the system architecture I'm not able to implement atomic requests we've got scenarios in which there's a request for creating a parent CONTENT which needs to call another Microservice and that Microservice has to call the same service again to create a Child CONTENT and if I'm using the decorator @transaction.atomic to make the CREATE request atomic then I'm not able to complete this whole cycle.

Comment: @IainShelvington

Comment: Is this accurate for the flow of what you  describe? 1) There is a request to create parent content 2) The parent content is saved 3) A request is made to another microservice 4) The microservice makes a request to our service to create child content 5) The child content is created and the microservice's request completes 6) Our request to the microservice completes 7) The initial create request then completes

Comment: Yes exactly this is how it is working

Comment: Do you have the option of using an asynchronous task queue like celery? Instead of having your app wait on the result of several back and forth calls you could just schedule a task to call the microservice after the initial create has completed, that way you __could__ have atomic requests and you wouldn't have this crazy chain of calls and waiting

Comment: We can consider this and if we go with a queue like celery or kafka then in that case if the request number 3) has a failure then we'll need to create another task to rollback the initial request right?

Comment: If the other microservice is unable to create the child content then the parent content has to be cleaned up? That's not happening now in the process you described, the parent is saved to the DB because the request is not atomic, unless you currently clean up afterwards and have a period where the incomplete data is temporarily in the DB?

Comment: It is being cleaned up if the Content microservice which makes the call 3) receives a failure response from the other microservice

Comment: @IainShelvington I'll share a diagram to make thing a little more clear

Comment: This process seems like a nightmare... having an external service make another request during a request and then trying to wrap that into a single mutation. Why does the other microservice call you and why does it need to be called to create the child? Could that microservice not respond in a format that you could use to create the child as this would make things a lot simpler?

Comment: can you have a look at this diagram: 
https://lucid.app/lucidchart/e6b4f09f-9c9f-49bd-9383-aab3effb1d6e/edit?viewport_loc=-124%2C-164%2C2219%2C1108%2C0_0&invitationId=inv_ed3c7436-aa4b-4a5a-9c53-ac49f6260f80

Comment: When MOD MS makes the call to create child content, what data does it send? Could that data not be sent in the response and handled in the original request instead?

Comment: Just one more thing, sorry for the spam. Is there a significant performance impact from not using the cache?

Comment: No, actually for the child to exist we need the parent to be existing before the child and before a child is created we need a few things to be done by the MOD MS like uploading relevant files,binaries, zips to the S3 storage and once that process is completed only then a child should be created

Comment: No problem @IainShelvington I should be the one Thanking you for being active here and Yes, the cache has a significant impact on the system

Comment: The only two options I can see right now are 1) use an asynchronous task queue, atomic requests and some clean up process 2) Have super granular and manual control of your cache and implement some kind of lock so that it's only updated when nothing is being created. Sorry I can't be much more help, this is one of those problems that you can spend weeks on

Comment: No worries @IainShelvington and yes, you are right